# Can this equation be expressed in terms of tan(x) somehow?

Tags: trigonometry

Here's the expression:

$${x \sin(x \log n)+ {1 \over 2}\cos(x \log n)}\over {x \cos(x \log n)- {1 \over 2}\sin (x \log n)}$$

From graphing it, it looks quite similar to the graph for $\tan(x \log n)$ (with asymptotes at the same points).

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $\cos(x\log n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not in terms of $\tan(xl)$ alone as the variable $x$ appears outside and inside the trigonometric functions.

You can write

$${{x \sin(x l)+ {1 \over 2}\cos(x l)}\over {x \cos(x l)- {1 \over 2}\sin (x l)} }=\frac{\tan(xl)+\frac1{2x}}{1-\tan(xl)\frac1{2x}}=\tan(xl+\text{arccot}(2x)).$$

The function $\text{arccot}$ is slowly varying and this may explain what you observe (though the vertical asymptotes do not coincide exactly with those of $\tan(xl)$).

Comment: Obviously, $l$ is short for $\log n$.

Comment: Ah!  Excellent!  This is great - much thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$${x \sin(x \log n)+ {1 \over 2}\cos(x \log n)}\over {x \cos(x \log n)- {1 \over 2}\sin (x \log n)}$$
$$={{x \cfrac{\sin(x \log n)}{\cos(x \log n)}+ {1 \over 2}}\over {x - {1 \over 2}\cfrac{\sin(x \log n)}{\cos(x \log n)}}}$$
$$={{x \tan(x \log n)+ {1 \over 2}}\over {x - {1 \over 2}\tan(x \log n)}}$$